# Git push local master to remote specific branch

Tags: git, merge, git-branch

I did changes in my local branch. Then I checkout to my master branch and merge it with my local branch. Now I want to push the changes in the master branch to specific branch at the remote. Say, we are 5 Developers. Each one having their own branch at remote repo. If I modified something at my local repo, I should push my work on the branch which is named in my name.

> How can I push that changes from my local repo master to my branch at
>   remote repo?

Once I pushed it to my branch at remote repo, I will inform my updation to my other team members.

> **How can they fetch and merge** my updation located in **my remote branch to their local master**?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To push from your local `master` to a different remote `branch`, use:

```
git push origin master:branch
```

To have your friends pull this remote `branch` into their local `master`, they can use `git pull` as:

```
git checkout master
git pull origin branch
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the remote branch name in [`git push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) command like this:

```
git push <remote> <local branch name>:<remote branch name>
```

So in your case, something like this:

```
git push origin master:smith-master
```

If you want to make this the default branch to push to, use the `-u` flag in addition.

Comment: Can I do it in 'bare' Remote repository?

Comment: Yes, you can do it in a bare remote repository.