# Automatically push local branch to a different branch on remote

Tags: git

How to configure Git so that when I do `git push` it automatically does this:

```
git push origin master:something_else
```

There are question on how to do this manually:

- [Git push local master to remote specific branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40254420/git-push-local-master-to-remote-specific-branch)
- [Push local master commits to remote branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206093/push-local-master-commits-to-remote-branch)

But how to have Git do this **automatically**?

I've tried the `--set-upstream-to` option but that only affects pulling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec#_pushing_refspecs

> ## Pushing Refspecs
>
> It’s nice that you can fetch namespaced references that way, but how does the QA team get their branches into a `qa/` namespace in the first place? You accomplish that by using refspecs to push.
>
> If the QA team wants to push their `master` branch to `qa/master` on the remote server, they can run
>
> ```
> $ git push origin master:refs/heads/qa/master
> ```
>
> If they want Git to do that automatically each time they run `git push origin`, they can add a `push` value to their config file (`/.git/config>`):
>
> ```
> [remote "origin"]
>     url = https://github.com/schacon/simplegit-progit
>     fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
>     push = refs/heads/master:refs/heads/qa/master
> ```
>
> Again, this will cause a `git push origin` to push the local `master` branch to the remote `qa/master` branch by default.

Comment: Yes, that is the way to do it - question was not quite clear : ). I think you can do this on the command line if you wanted to automate it, somthing like: `git config remote.origin.push = refs/heads/master:refs/heads/qa/master`, not quite sure the syntax on that one, so check it first :o ... this overrides the git push.default